# fastest way to find euclidean distance in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, euclidean-distance

I have 2 sets of 2D points (A and B), each set have about 540 points. I need to find the points in set B that are farther than a defined distance alpha from all the points in A.

I have a solution, but is not fast enough

```
# find the closest point of each of the new point to the target set
def find_closest_point( self, A, B):
    outliers = []
    for i in range(len(B)):
        # find all the euclidean distances
        temp = distance.cdist([B[i]],A)
        minimum = numpy.min(temp)
        # if point is too far away from the rest is consider outlier
        if minimum > self.alpha :
            outliers.append([i, B[i]])
        else:
            continue
    return outliers
```

I am using python 2.7 with numpy and scipy. Is there another way to do this that I may gain a considerable increase in speed?

Thanks in advance for the answers

Comment: possible duplicate of [Euclidean distance between points in two different Numpy arrays, not within](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871536/euclidean-distance-between-points-in-two-different-numpy-arrays-not-within) or [calculate euclidean distance with numpy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401712/calculate-euclidean-distance-with-numpy)

Comment: Since you seem to look for outliers only, which is a nearest neighbour search. I think you can (and should) use `scipy.spatial.KDTree` (the old cKDTree probably does not support that, so use a newer scipy where cKDTree does).

Comment: also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19277244/fast-weighted-euclidean-distance-between-points-in-arrays/19285289#19285289

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
>>> A = np.random.randn(540, 2)
>>> B = np.random.randn(540, 2)
>>> alpha = 1.
>>> ind = np.all(cdist(A, B) > alpha, axis=0)
>>> outliers = B[ind]
```

gives you the points you want.

Comment: Actually this gives me a set of True and False, though I think that I got an idea of what you wanted to do, and actually is a huge speed improvement.

Comment: now it works fine, and i got a big increase in speed aprox. from 9.5 to 0.6 for 10 tries of the whole algorithm, thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you have a very large set of points you could calculate x & y bounds of a add & subtract aplha then eliminate all the points in b from specific consideration that lay outside of that boundary.